# Infinite graph theory: What's a tree?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Consider a finite graph $G$: $G$ is a tree if it satisfies any of the following equivalent conditions:

(1) $G$ is connected and no cycle can be a subgraph of $G$.

(2) $G$ is connected and no cycle can be an induced subgraph of $G$.

If $G$ is infinite (countably), clearly (1) implies (2) but does (2) imply (1)?

Comment: I guess I'm a little curious how (1) isn't the definition of a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) which is certainly not necessarily a tree (which is essentially a "rooted" DAG).

Comment: @Jared: Your version of "tree" is the computer science definition (and of course the best because it's the natural recursive form). In mathematics a tree is usually undirected.

Comment: The same proof as for the finite case works for the infinite case. What have you tried?

Comment: And it does not have to be countable.

Comment: @Jared: I should add that the recursive definition of course does not work for most infinite mathematical trees. But then the natural question is, why call them trees anymore? They should be just called acyclic graphs...

Comment: @user21820 I disagree with the sentiment that in computer science  trees are (almost) always directed. That is true if the tree in question is rooted (which indeed is often the case). However, trees described by the OP are unrooted, and these also happen frequently in computer science and they do not come with any default way of directing the edges (unless, of course, the underlying graph was directed in the first place).

Comment: @dtldarek: Well, that depends on what you mean. If you use a graph library, then the root of a tree may be hidden from you, but if you do everything yourself then almost always undirected graphs are stored using bidirectional edges, and typically we would have a distinguished vertex that we always start from when we want to utilize the properties of trees. Such as MSTs, which are not intrinsically rooted but when we use them we typically root them. Put another way, the ability to root a tree and do DFS on it is crucial in many algorithms, so trees are most useful rooted if it is not already.

Comment: @user21820 I think we disagree on something else entirely, and if that is true then I misunderstood your comment. Frequently we impose some additional structure on an object to make it easier to handle (like a root in a tree). However, unless that structure was there in the first place (i.e. it was intrinsic to that object), I would not say that this object has/had this structure. For example, if I direct edges of a graph, I say I create a new graph. Assuming that the imposed structure becomes the property of an object, I clearly agree with you.

Comment: @dtldarek: Yea I don't think we actually disagree. My point is simply that usually the concept of a tree in computer science is a rooted one and is also implemented that way or converted into one, otherwise it cannot be used easily. The rooted version has a recursive structure that is absent in a general acyclic graph, and that recursive structure is important in most CS applications. Maybe I went too far in saying "the CS definition" but it's surely the natural definition of a tree in computer science and also in general for anyone who was not taught the acyclic graph definition.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint (same proof as for the finite case)**

> If there is a cycle (and by **definition** there are only finite cycles), then pick the smallest cycle and figure out whether it is an induced subgraph.